# different values in variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Why do I have different values of `i` in `main` and `foo`?

Here is my sample code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>

double a;
int i;
int j;
int nr_threads;

void foo()
{
    printf("foo::i: \t%d\n", i);
}


int main()
{
    puts("hejka");
    a = 0;

    nr_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf("Threads: %d\n", nr_threads);

    omp_set_num_threads(7);

#pragma omp parallel private(i,j) shared(a)
{
   #pragma omp single
    {
        nr_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("Threads: %d\n", nr_threads);
    }

#pragma omp for reduction(+:a)
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("main::i:\t%d\n", i);
        foo();
    }
}

    printf("a: %lf\n",a);
    printf("i: %d\n",i);
    printf("j: %d\n",j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given that printf has no thread guarantees, I'm pretty sure anything you're doing with it here could be termed "undefined".

Comment: Bo Persson, why not?
Robinson, how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `i` inside your parallel section.

I think the 'copyin' `#pragma` (or something like that) can be used to clone the value into each thread when the parallel section is launched.

Thread-private variables are not initialized.

If memory serves, thread=private class objects are default constructed, however.

Comment: in for(i=0;i<10;i++) is i=0, so it is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the loop variable of a `parallel for` is implicitly made private for every worker thread, so each thread will get a private variable `i`. There is no connection between the `i` seen by the worker threads and the `i` seen by the main thread, except for the name.

Comment: Ok, i understand your explanation. But how to fix this?

Comment: @TBom: Why would you want to fix it? If you make the `i` shared (assuming it's possible), your program will give completely incorrect results, because all threads will increment the same `i` and not process the array correctly.

Comment: I don't want to share `i`. I want private-global variable `i`

Comment: A variable can't be simultaneously private and global. What do you mean?

Comment: I don't understand this, why not?

Comment: @TBom: Because you can either have the variable visible to all threads, in which case you will have undefined behavior is multiple threads modify the same variable, or you can have the variable private for each thread.

Comment: OK, so I have to pass variables as parameter. Thanks